# How to use realm in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use relamDb in my react native expo project. I run the following command to install realm in my project-

**npm install --save realm**

it doesn't show any error while installing. After installing, in my project I have created two classes - **App.js** and **TodoListComponent.js**

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import TodoListComponent from './components/TodoListComponent';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TodoListComponent/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**TodoListComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { updateTodoList, deleteTodoList, queryAllTodoLists } from '../databases/allSchemas';
import realm from '../databases/allSchemas';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';

import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent';
import PopupDialogComponent from './PopupDialogComponent';
let FlatListItem = props => {
    const { itemIndex, id, name, creationDate, popupDialogComponent, onPressItem } = props;
    showEditModal = () => {
        popupDialogComponent.showDialogComponentForUpdate({
            id, name
        });
    }
    showDeleteConfirmation = () => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Delete',
            'Delete a todoList',
            [
                {
                    text: 'No', onPress: () => { },//Do nothing
                    style: 'cancel'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Yes', onPress: () => {
                        deleteTodoList(id).then().catch(error => {
                            alert(`Failed to delete todoList with id = ${id}, error=${error}`);
                        });
                    }
                },
            ],
            { cancelable: true }
        );
    };
    return (
        <Swipeout right={[
            {
                text: 'Edit',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(81,134,237)',
                onPress: showEditModal
            },
            {
                text: 'Delete',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(217, 80, 64)',
                onPress: showDeleteConfirmation
            }
        ]} autoClose={true}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressItem}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: itemIndex % 2 == 0 ? 'powderblue' : 'skyblue' }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18, margin: 10 }}>{name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, margin: 10 }} numberOfLines={2}>{creationDate.toLocaleString()}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Swipeout >
    );
}
export default class TodoListComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todoLists: []
        };
        this.reloadData();
        realm.addListener('change', () => {
            this.reloadData();
        });
    }
    reloadData = () => {
        queryAllTodoLists().then((todoLists) => {
            this.setState({ todoLists });
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ todoLists: [] });
        });
        console.log(`reloadData`);
    }
    render() {
        return (<View style={styles.container}>
            <HeaderComponent title={"Todo List"}
                hasAddButton={true}
                hasDeleteAllButton={true}
                showAddTodoList={
                    () => {
                        this.refs.popupDialogComponent.showDialogComponentForAdd();
                    }
                }
            />
            <FlatList
                style={styles.flatList}
                data={this.state.todoLists}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => <FlatListItem {...item} itemIndex={index}
                    popupDialogComponent={this.refs.popupDialogComponent}
                    onPressItem={() => {
                        alert(`You pressed item `);
                    }} />}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
            <PopupDialogComponent ref={"popupDialogComponent"} />
        </View>);
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    flatList: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    }
});
```

After these coding, when I run the application it shows the following error-

missing Realm constructor. Did you run "react-native link realm" ? Please see https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#missing-realm-constructor for troubleshooting

[image: Missing Realm constructor error screenshot]

I have tried to find out problem from the below links-

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1407

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1340

But none of these were helpful to me. So, it would be very nice if some one helps me to know how to use realmDb in React native expo project.

Answer (score 0):

Expo does not support realm.

You will have to eject from expo and then start using realm

Please note that Expo does not support Realm, From the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Old Question, but you can now by using their template:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@realm/expo-template-ts

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start-expo/